# How to enable sessions in my Ubuntu Server

Tags: java, session, session-variables

I have a little problem with my Ubuntu Server. The server can't hold cookie sessions... if I want to keep the session, I have to use the method **response.encodeURL** in every URL of the website. The server manager told me that I need to install something to enable the session cookies. With session I mean what you use to save the data when somone logs in like: **session.setAttribute();**

My question then is, what should I install? Since the server manager doesnt know.

**WEB STACK**

Operating System: Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Web Server: GlassFish Server 4.1.1

Database: MySQL (I manage the database from phpMyAdmin)

Programing language: Java Server Pages

Comment: You haven't mentioned which web stack you are using.

Comment: I update the question now @StephenC

Comment: You shouldn't need to install anything.  It is probably just a configuration item; e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/beaxr.html

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue??